# On PyLint, disable specific warning on specif files using rcfile

Tags: python, pylint

Salutations, all.

I'm working on a python project and have been tasked with cleaning the pylint warnings. Things is, there are specific parts of the code that require indentation or spacing between words that go against Pylint.
Question: is there a way to disable specific pyling warnings on specific files from the rcfile? Like disable wrong continued indentation on files named *tests.py, without making it affect every file.
I'd just add the pylint comment on files, but I was advised against that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ignore` option in the configuration file or add `# pylint: disable=all` on the top of the python file.

Comment: Well, thanks for replying, but as I said, I'm not supposed to add #pyling: lines on each file.